# Imagemagic and php exec: convert: no images defined

Tags: php, imagemagick

The command works just fine from the shell

```
/opt/ImageMagick/bin/convert /private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/pdfPyflQF /private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/imgRilIdW 2>&1
```

I got image generated. But if I run it with `php` `exec` function I get error

```
Array
(
    [0] => convert: no images defined `/private/var/folders/nl/9cky1krj5_j7zwm34tfkndd40000gn/T/imgRilIdW' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
)
```

Seems it's not permission issue. File permissions are 666. Can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Usually error "convert: no images defined" is coming when `convert` couldn't find `gs` tool.

I had the same problem and solved it with defining PATH environment before doing `shell_exec` like this:

```
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/local/bin/');
```

Because `gs` tool is located in the /opt/local/bin.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see a file extension on the input or output images.

It would probably be worth enclosing your image path in " " and what actual code are you using in exec()